# scrollview not move to other page when I add an existing view

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

1 - I created a uiviewcontroller and put a scrollview into it. I am scolling to navigate between pages and also using a pagecontroller at the bottom.
2 - When I added labels to the scrollview, everything went OK.
3 - But scrollview doesn't scroll to the next page when I add an existing uiview into my scrollview with following code ;

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
scroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(4608, 796);

contentView.frame = CGRectMake(2, 2, 768, 760); //this is my existing uiview which has some components (text box,image view etc.) in it.

// I am creating labels dynamically at specific positions
UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d. pagem",0];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
label.frame = CGRectMake(1, 0, 768, 780);

// I create another uilabel here
UILabel* label2 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
label2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d. pagem",1];
label2.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
label2.frame = CGRectMake(768 +1, 0, 768, 780);

[scroller addSubview:contentView]; // when i add uiview to the scoller, scroller not scoll to the next page
[scroller addSubview:label];  // scroller works fine when i remove the code above (adding uiview) and add this label.
[scroller addSubview:label2];

[self.scroller setDelegate:self];
pageControl.numberOfPages = 3;
pageControl.currentPage = 0;
[self changeThePage:nil];

[super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender
{
if (changeUsed) return;

float pageWidth = scroller.frame.size.width;
int page = floor((scroller.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
if (scroller.contentOffset.x >200)
{
    page++;
}

if (page >-1 && page<6)
{
    pageControl.currentPage = page;
}
}

- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
changeUsed = NO;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
changeUsed = NO;
}

- (IBAction)changeThePage:(id)sender
{
int pagem = pageControl.currentPage;
NSLog(@"the page is : %d", pagem);
CGRect frame = scroller.frame;
frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * pagem;
frame.origin.y = 0;
[scroller scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
changeUsed = YES;
}
```

4 - Everything works fine again once I remove my existing uiview from the uiscrollview and its declaration.

I don't know why uiview prevent scrolling of uiscrollview?

Comment: If you want it to automatically scroll to the last page when you add information to it the you need to call `setContentOffset` on the scrollview and manually move it to the next page.  The contentoffset doesn't automatically change when you change the contentsize of a scrollview.

Comment: I am not sure if this can help me. Putz,I don't want it to automatically scroll to the last page or any page.This is a simple project that already works fine if i do not add an uiview. That's the weird point.I can move my finger on screen and it bounces as well, but doesn't go to the next page.Please let me know if I could not describe my problem might be because of my poor english. Sorry for this.

Comment: In your xib or storyboard is the Use Autolayout checked?

Comment: I resolved by change the method. I used UIImageViews for each page unfortunately.